# Neo4j gem undefined method `name' for CypherNode

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I'm currently experiencing an issue where it looks like CypherNodes aren't being converted into their corresponding model objects properly.

Interestingly enough, if I clear my DB locally, the error stops occurring, but will sure enough occur sometime later. Once it has occurred it consistently produces the error.

The main bit of code where the issue occurs resembles the following:

```
results = Club.query_as(:club)
             .match("(region:Region)-[:has_club]->(club)")
             .match("(club)-[:last_event]->()<-[:next*0..]-(event)-[:action]->(game)")
             .match("(game)<-[:action]-(:Event)<-[:next*0..]-()<-[:first_event]-(member:Member)")
             .where(region: { name: region_name }, club: { name: club_name })
             .order(event: { created_at: :desc })
             .limit(limit)
             .pluck(:member, :event, :game)


  results.map do |member, event, game|
    # Error occurs on 'game.name' as game is a CypherNode, not a Game object
    view_model = GameViewModel.new(game: game.name,
                                   member_name: member.nickname,
                                   created_at: event.created_at.to_i)
  end
```

When the problem occurs, this results in an array with items that look like:

```
[ 
  CypherNode 1139 (70254694683340), 
  #<Event uuid: "c3b81116-1be3-4722-8908-8c36d5c76fe3", created_at: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 03:53:43 +0000>, 
  CypherNode 993 (70254694681800)
 ]
```

If I look into each CypherNode (node.labels, node.props), I can see that it has the correct label in an array, and the correct properties on it.

The member model is quite complex, but the game model is very simple and looks like:

```
class Game
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :name, type: String
end
```

I'm kind of stuck with this, not knowing exactly what to look at. Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: What version of the `neo4j` and `neo4j-core` gems are you using?

Comment: Also if you'd like to chat with us our Gitter channel is https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j

Comment: I'm currently on neo4j 5.1.0, neo4j-core 5.1.0. Thanks for the gitter channel link! I'm travelling atm, but will hop on there for sure :)

Comment: Definitely pop into the Gitter room when you have a chance. Are you using Rails? I can't think of why this would happen but I have some ideas about where the offending code may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to a bug that was patched in 5.1.5, regressed in 5.2.0-5.2.2, fixed again in release 5.2.3. https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/955 addresses it.

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly strange!  Some thoughts:

- I think you already covered this, but the labels should be `Member` and `Game` (case-sensitive).  I see your matching on `Member` in the query but not on `Game` (that doesn't matter as long as the label on the node is right, but just to check)
- If you're using `self.mapped_label_name` in your model that could affect things
- Do any of these nodes have multiple labels?  Again, I don't think that will make a difference, but it's good to know

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not using self.mapped_label_name, and none of the nodes have multiple labels. I'll have to see if I can work out how to recreate the error as it's pretty sporadic atm.

Comment: Gotcha.  Definitely let us know if you can reproduce!